# 7 Erogenous Zones by Monica

Tags: friends

In Friends S04E11, Monica describes 7 erogenous zones in women.

What zones are these? My guess was something like this picture (NSFW):

> [image]

Have they been properly listed in some official form?

Edit: to clarify, I'm not asking about which zones are erogenous for women in real-life. I am asking about which zones Monica was specifically mentioning, and whether there is an official reference about them. Googling this topic, there [are](https://www.buzzfeed.com/robinedds/seven-seven-seven-seven-seven?utm_term=.yw9pAx6aK#.qj85KEDdZ) [several](https://www.quora.com/What-were-the-7-erogenous-zones-in-women-mentioned-by-Monica-Geller-in-11th-episode-of-Friends-in-season-4-And-how-much-accuracy-is-in-it) [websites](https://www.scoopwhoop.com/Erogenous-Zones-Women-Monica-Seven-FRIENDS/#.5vumar9j0) with such lists, but they are not related with Friends, as far as I can tell.

Comment: A good Google search will yield you proper results.

Comment: Each website shows a different set of zones. My question is not what real-life's women's erogenous zones are, just what Monica meant they were.

Comment: All zones marked in that image are true. I can tell that after watching this video. She mentioned 7 a lot of times in the end and that's that 7th point as mentioned in your image. I hope that helps.

Comment: I would elaborate this to the following moment when Chandler jokes that he was looking upside down and Rachel says: "Well you know. Sometimes that helps". I could throw some guesses about what she meant, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score -1):

The Erogenous Zones on the Female Body
Clitoris. A runaway winner for the title of 
"Body Part Contributing Most to Sexual Arousal," 
the clitoris is extremely sensitive. ...
Vagina. 
Heard of the famous mecca of sexual pleasure that is the female "G-spot?" ...
Cervix. ...
Mouth and Lips. ...
Neck. ...
Breasts and Nipples. ...
Ears.